# Sequelize: Unknown column *.createdAt in 'field list'

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I've come across this problem several times in the past and have read a number of solutions. Before I go through them again, I was hoping someone could explain exactly what the problem is - because despite eventually fixing it, I never really understand *why*

The error:

`original: Error: Unknown column 'job.createdAt' in 'field list'`

What I assume is the source (as I just added it):

`[Sequelize.fn('date_format', Sequelize.col('job.createdAt' ), '%d/%m/%y'), 'jobDate']`

The error suggests that `createdAt` isn't a column in the jobs table - several solutions suggest defining `createdAt` in your model (which I'd already done).

What also confuses me is that in workbench I can run the query:
`SELECT * FROM test.jobs ORDER BY test.jobs.createdAt;`
and it works, and that I don't have this problem with the equivalent `Company` attribute.

**Job Model:**

```
const Job = sequelize.define('job', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },

    ...

    createdAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE(3),
        allowNull: false,
    },
    updatedAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE(3),
        allowNull: false,
    }
});
```

**The options object for the query:**

```
const options = {
    include: [
        {
            model: Job,
            attributes: [
                'id',
                'title',
                // ...
                'createdAt',
                [Sequelize.fn('date_format', Sequelize.col('job.createdAt' ), '%d/%m/%y'), 'jobDate'],

            ]
        },
    ],
    attributes: [ 
        'id', 
        'name',
        'createdAt',
        [Sequelize.fn('date_format', Sequelize.col('company.createdAt' ), '%d/%m/%y'), 'companyDate'],
    ],
    order: [[ orderField, orderDirection ]],
    distinct: true
}
```

Workbench showing the column:

[image: column info]

As far as I can tell the relevant part(?) of the actual sql query looks right too

```
`jobs`.`createdAt` AS `jobs.createdAt`, date_format(`job`.`createdAt`, '%d/%m/%y') AS `jobs.jobDate`,
```

Appreciate any help

Comment: From a glance, (looking at the SQL) it looks like it should be `Sequelize.col('jobs.createdAt')` (plural).

Comment: Amazing, thanks! Have you any idea why both my Models can be singular, the tables both plural, and yet `Sequelize.col('company.createdAt' )` works fine and `Sequelize.col('job.createdAt' )` does not? Either way, thanks, that's perfect!

Comment: it could be multiple possible reasons. if `company` use `freezeTableName` or `tableName` which can avoid the Sequelize's auto pluralization.  Or table is created by DB directly instead of via Sequelize, etc.

Comment: It doesn't do any of those things, strangely. The only difference is that `Job` defines its own `createdAt` field explicitly. And I've just noticed is defined in a file/module called `jobs` plural (but it can't be that, that's just the file name, right?). Ether way, thanks a lot for your response, I'll definitely pay more attention to pluralisation in the future!